# Подскажите как выполнить проверку даты

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

В постах проставляется начальная и конечная дата, если текущая дата попадает в этот диапазон - посты выводятся, если не попадает - выводится счетчик.

Есть вот такой код:

1. Дату вывода постов я получаю в формате `20171023` в счетчике она должна быть в формате `October 27, 2017 00:00:00`, получится ли у меня её преобразовать или лучше сразу получать её в таком формате?
2. Как получить ближайшую дату, что бы передать её в счётчик? Нужно проверить даты всех постов и выбрать самую ближайшую.

   ```
       <?php

           $today = date('Ymd');

           $args = array(
               'post_type' => 'flash-sale',
               'posts_per_page' => -1,
               'meta_query' => array(
                   array(
                       'key'       => 'start_sales',
                       'compare'   => '<=',
                       'value'     => $today,
                   ),
                   array(
                       'key'       => 'end_sales',
                       'compare'   => '>=',
                       'value'     => $today,
                   )
               ),
           );

           $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>

           <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
               <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

                   <?php the_title('<h3>','</h3>'); ?>
                   <?php the_content(); ?>


               <?php endwhile; ?>

               <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

           <?php else : ?>

               <div class="countdown-sale">
                   <div class="countdown" data-date="October 27, 2017 00:00:00"></div>
                   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus rhoncus sapien ut ipsum condimentum, sit amet pellentesque lorem vulputate.</p>
                   <script type="text/javascript">
                       jQuery(function() {
                           var endDate = "December 1, 2017 00:00:00";

                           jQuery('.countdown').countdown({ date: endDate });

                       });
                   </script>
               </div>

           <?php endif; ?>
   ```

Comment: опубликуйте Ваше решение в поле для ответа и отметьте его как решение (серая галка слева от текста ответа)

Comment: "Вы можете принять свой ответ завтра"

Comment: да, есть такое ограничение для самоответов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решен, мой вариант решения ниже:

```
<?php
    $today = date('Ymd');

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'flash-sale',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key'       => 'start_sales',
                'compare'   => '<=',
                'value'     => $today,
            ),
            array(
                'key'       => 'end_sales',
                'compare'   => '>=',
                'value'     => $today,
            )
        ),
    );

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

?>

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

        <?php the_title('<h3>','</h3>'); ?>
        <?php the_content(); ?>


    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php else : ?>

    <?php

    $today = date('Ymd');

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'flash-sale',
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'orderby' => 'meta_value',
        'meta_key'  => 'start_sales',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key'       => 'start_sales',
                'compare'   => '>=',
                'value'     => $today,
            )
        ),
    );

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
    <?php

    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
            $the_query->the_post(); ?>

            <?php
            $feature_sale = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'start_sales' );
            $date = strtotime($feature_sale[0]);
            $new_date = date('F j, Y H:i:s', $date);

            ?>

            <div class="countdown-sale">
                <div class="countdown" data-date="<?php echo $new_date ?>"></div>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus rhoncus sapien ut ipsum condimentum, sit amet pellentesque lorem vulputate.</p>
                <button class="button alt modal-trigger" data-modal="subscribe-modal">Subscribe</button>
                <div class="modal-overlay" id="subscribe-modal">
                    <div class="modal-container">
                        <div class="holder">
                            <div class="modal">
                                <div class="close icon-close"></div>
                                <div class="smart-forms">
                                    <div class="form-body">
                                        <?php gravity_form(3, false, false, false, '', true, 12); ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    jQuery(function() {

                        var endDate = "<?php echo date('F j, Y') . ' 00:00:00' ?>";

                        jQuery('.countdown').countdown({
                            date: endDate,
                            onEnd: function() {
                                jQuery(this.el).addClass('ended');
                            }
                        });

                    });
                </script>
            </div>

        <?php } ?>

        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

    <?php } ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Здесь идет выборка постов, которые попадают в диапазон дат `start_sales` и `end_sales`. Формат даты как я и писал `20171023`

```
    <?php
    $today = date('Ymd');

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'flash-sale',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key'       => 'start_sales',
                'compare'   => '<=',
                'value'     => $today,
            ),
            array(
                'key'       => 'end_sales',
                'compare'   => '>=',
                'value'     => $today,
            )
        ),
    );

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

?>
```

Если посты не попадают в этот диапазон, идет сортировка постов по `meta_value`. Таким образом я получаю сортировку постов по возрастанию и получаю дату ближайшего поста. Это необходимо для того чтоб передать текущую дату и дату поста в countdown.

```
    <?php

$today = date('Ymd');

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'flash-sale',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'meta_key'  => 'start_sales',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'       => 'start_sales',
            'compare'   => '>=',
            'value'     => $today,
        )
    ),
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
```

Но так как для countdown используется готовая библиотека, нужно преобразовать это в нужный формат даты `October 27, 2017 00:00:00`. Здесь я получаю нужный формат даты, который передаю в атрибут **data-date=""** `<div class="countdown" data-date="<?php echo $new_date ?>"></div>`

```
    <?php

        $feature_sale = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'start_sales' );
        $date = strtotime($feature_sale[0]);
        $new_date = date('F j, Y H:i:s', $date);

    ?>
```

Ну и наконец я указываю в скрипте текущую дату, также приведенную в нужный формат

```
    var endDate = "<?php echo date('F j, Y') . ' 00:00:00' ?>";
```

P.S.: понимаю, что код можно было сделать красивее, но это мое быстрое решение. Если есть варианты - предлагайте

Comment: Чтобы дополнить свой вопрос, просим вас воспользоваться опцией редактирования. Кнопку «Опубликовать ответ» следует использовать только для исчерпывающих ответов на вопросы. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/207025)

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja это ответ, не торопитесь при проверке вопросов и ответов из очереди проверок.

Comment: И каково, собственно, решение? Прокомментируйте, пожалуйста, код и как именно он решает проблему прямо в теле ответа.